# Cannot perform save because document has been modified by the session and is also taking part in deferred PATCH command RavenDB

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I am trying to perform a patch command in Ravendb c# and am receiving this error. What I'm going is creating a new entry then trying to save it.

Here is the relevent classes for handling the json serializing, deserializing.

```
    public class Merchant
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "venues")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<Venue> venues { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="files")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<File> files { get; set; }
}

public class Venue
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tills")]
    public List<Till> tills { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "files")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<File> files { get; set; }
}

public class Till
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "files")]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<File> files { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "logs")]
    public List<Log> logs { get; set; }
}
```

// here's the function that is called first.

```
 public bool AddMerchant(Merchant m)
    {
        bool returnbool = false; // set to false at begining.
        if (DoesServiceExist("RavenDB"))
        {
            StartService("RavenDB");
            returnbool = true;

            using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(m);
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return returnbool;
    }
```

here's where my problem starts, I call this function and it tells me that I cannot perform this action due to it being in a deferred patch statement.

```
 public void AddVenue(string idArg, Venue venue = null)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {

            var merchant = session.Load<Merchant>(idArg);
            List<Venue> venuesList = new List<Venue>();
            if (merchant.venues == null) { session.Advanced.Patch(merchant, m => m.venues, venuesList); }
            else
            {
                session.Advanced.Patch(merchant,
                x => x.venues,
                venues => venues.Add(venue));
            }
            session.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Upon research I believed that the Defer in ravendb refered to this:

```
session.advanced().defer(new PatchCommandData("blogposts/1", null, patchRequest, null));
```

Which I never call.

Any help would be welcome.

// final answer is below, thank you.

```
    public void AddVenue(Merchant merchant, Venue venue = null)
    {
        using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
        {
            Merchant merchantLocal = session.Load<Merchant>(merchant.Id);
            var changeVector = session.Advanced.GetChangeVectorFor(merchantLocal);
            if(merchantLocal.venues == null) { merchantLocal.venues = new List<Venue>(); }
            merchantLocal.venues.Add(venue);
            session.Store(merchantLocal, changeVector, merchantLocal.Id);
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, the venues property has changed so at '`SaveChanges`' time the patch operation cannot be applied.

Read about **Patching documents and concurrent modifications** in 
https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch04/Ch04.md#patching-documents-and-concurrent-modifications

1. If you know the document ID, then don't use Load at all.
    
   Just call `Patch` and `SaveChanges`.

   **OR**
2. Apply Patch only on some condition

```
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{
    var merchant = session.Load<Merchant>(idArg);

    if (merchant.venues  !=  SOME_CONDITION )
    throw new
        InvalidOperationException("venues have changed. Cannot apply patch Operation");

    List<Venue> venuesList = new List<Venue>();

    if (merchant.venues == null) { 
        session.Advanced.Patch(merchant, m => m.venues, venuesList); 
    }
    else {
        session.Advanced.Patch(merchant,
        x => x.venues,
        venues => venues.Add(venue));
    }

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Working on fixing it now.

Comment: Thank you, that works. Adding final code to original post.